# What is the difference between NSString and NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c

I need a clarification regarding the difference between the NSString and NSMutableString. Can any one expand briefly?

Comment: I think you can get a good idea what they do by examining the methods available on each.

Answer (score 36):

**Suppose You have a code like this**

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

s = [s stringByAppendingString:@"World"];
```

**and other code like this**

```
NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];

[ms appendString:@"World"];
```

Both of these, functionally, do the same thing except for one difference - the top code block leaks. -[NSString stringByAppendingString:] generates a new immutable NSString object which you then tell the pointer s to point to. In the process, however, you orphan the NSString object that s originally pointed to. Replacing the line as follows would get rid of the leak:

```
s = [[s autorelease] stringByAppendingString:@"World"];
```

Comment: Is this still a problem with the ARC framework?

Answer (score 36):

The difference between **NSMutableString** and **NSString** is that

**NSMutableString:** *NSMutableString* objects provide methods to modify the underlying array of characters they represent, while *NSString* does not. For example, *NSMutableString* exposes methods such as *appendString*, *deleteCharactersInRange*, *insertString*, *replaceOccurencesWithString*, etc. All these methods operate on the string as it exists in memory.

**NSString:** on the other hand only is a *create-once-then-read-only string* if you will; you'll find that all of its "manipulation" methods (substring, uppercaseString, etc) return other NSString objects and never actually modify the existing string in memory.

Answer (score 9):

An NSString instance cannot be modified once it's initialized - it is "immutable."  No NSString methods can modify the string's value.

NSMutableString on the other hand can be modified after it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Andy White's answer, there may be performance benefits to using NSString instead of NSMutableString in your code (as always, test using Apple's performance tools to make sure this is truly where your performance bottleneck is). In the situation where you want to change the value of an NSString, one option is to create a entirely new NSString with the altered value in it and then destroy the old NSString.